# Password/Username won't work using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I'm attempting to create a very simple CMS with PHP and MYSQL. The problem I'm having is that whenever I attempt to log in, if I put in the wrong username, what I want to happen happens. It goes to a screen that says wrong input and has a link going back to the login page. However if I put in the correct username and the wrong password it just reloads the page and if I put in the correct password, the same screen comes up as if I put in the wrong  username, telling me the user name or password is wrong. I've checked the database to make sure the password I'm entering is correct and the username and password are both correct yet it's not working. Can anyone help me out with this? Thank you in advance

Here are the functions that you may need to see:

```
function verifyUser($name, $pass)
{
// Escape strings
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$password - mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

$result = mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and       password-'$password' limit 1");

if (mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    return true;
} else{
    return false;
}

}

function validateUser($name, $pass)
{
    $check = verifyUser($name, md5($pass));

    if($check)
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';

        header('Location: http://localhost/cms/admin/index.php');

    } else{

        echo'Please enter a correct username and password <br />';
        echo "<a href='http://localhost/cms/admin/login.php'>Try Again?</a>";
        exit;
    }



}
```

Here is the login.php file:

```
require_once '../functions.php';

connect();

if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'])
{
$result = validateUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
}


?>

<form method="post" action="">
<p>
    <label for="name">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
</p>

<p>
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

I am receiving one Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\login.php on line 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `die();` after your `header('Location: ...');` line in successful login attempt.

To correct the undefined index error, change this in login.php:

`if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) )`

Additionally, you have an error in your query. The minus sign should be an equal sign (you had `password-'$password'`. Unless you need to capture user data, you should try counting the results, instead of fetching them.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and       password='$password' limit 1");

if ( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 )
```

Comment: Okay this fixes most of the problems except for that when I enter the correct combination, the login page just reloads instead of redirecting to the index.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Basically, the line `if (mysql_fetch_array($result))` is the problem. It's not necessarily a boolean answer like your if/else expects. Instead, it either returns a resource or a `FALSE`. Therefore, `$check` will never be given the value of `true`.

Additionally, but importantly, the functions you are using are being deprecated. Read up on [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: What then would be the proper function to work in this case? I'm still very much learning and I was going off a tutorial for this

Comment: `if (mysql_num_rows($result))` - note the other answer adds an unnecessary `> 0`. You limit the query to 1 result max, so the only possibilities are 1 (correct credentials) or 0 (incorrect credentials).

Comment: Also @cadavid4j, definitely read into the two alternatives. If you're writing new code, you really should learn functions that aren't being deprecated!

Comment: I do appreciate the help. I'm still very much in the learning process of PHP and MYSQL and I'm trying to teach it to myself over the summer right now during school breaks. So forgive my terrible code. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be trivial but notice you have '-' instead of '=' after the password variable, twice

```
    $password - mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

$result = mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and       password-'$password' limit 1");
```

Comment: I fixed this one already. After someone pointed out the other one I saw this one as well. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

use correct query

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from users where username='{$username}'
 AND password='{$password}' limit 1");
if($result){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```

and also use

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
$check=verifyuser($_POST["username"],sha1($_POST["password"]));//sha1 is more secure than md5
}
```